# @iOSFindBy is displayed as deprecated, what can I use instead (using pagefactory for Hybrid usage of Android and iOS device))

Tags: appium, appium-ios, appium-android, appium-snackbar

I have no experience with iOS, but I am trying to redesign my Android Project for the iOS Guys to use it as well for iOS.

After search in internet I find out that this can happens by using the page factory and locating elements by @iOSFindBy, 
After trying to use @iOSFindby for locating element using the page factory method, the compiler indicate that it is deprecated.

```
@iOSFindBy (Accessibility = "button_login")    
@AndroidFindBy(id = "net.myApp.int:id/loginBtn")    
private MobileElement login_Button2;
```

[image]

what Can I use instead of this?

I saw also in Appium java client (https://static.javadoc.io/io.appium/java-client/7.0.0/index.html?deprecated-list.html) :

*io.appium.java_client.pagefactory
Annotation Type iOSFindBy
Deprecated. 
UIAutomation is going to get deprecated. Use iOSXCUITFindBy instead It is recommended to use XCUITest

> @Retention(value=RUNTIME)  @Target(value={FIELD,TYPE}) 
>   @Repeatable(value=iOSFindBySet.class) public @interface iOSFindBy

Used to mark a field on a Page Object to indicate an alternative mechanism for locating the element or a list of elements. Used in conjunction with PageFactory this allows users to quickly and easily create PageObjects. using iOS UI selectors, accessibility, id, name, class name, tag and xpath*

but I dont know if this is the solution and how to use 
If I use it in my Code also get Error:

```
@iOSXCUITFindBy Accessibility = "button_login"
@AndroidFindBy(id = "net.myApp.int:id/loginBtn")
private MobileElement login_Button1;
```

Annotation are not allowed here.

Thanks for any Tip in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to know how things work is to check related tests in **appium-java-client** repository on [github](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/src/test/java/io/appium/java_client/pagefactory_tests/XCUITModeTest.java):

```java
    @iOSXCUITFindBy(accessibility = "IntegerB")
    private MobileElement textField2;
```

So in your case, it should be:

```java
    @iOSXCUITFindBy(accessibility = "button_login")
    @AndroidFindBy(id = "net.myApp.int:id/loginBtn")
    private MobileElement login_Button1;
```

Comment: Thanks for Hint and support. I have no chance to test it but at least no Compiler Error and I assume that it works. Many Thanks